# Evaluate Bash mathematical expression from file

Tags: linux, bash

I created a text file called `multiply.txt` and inside that text file there is just `2*3`.

What would be a one line command to compute the result of the expression in the `multiply.txt` file by only using the `echo` and `cat` commands?

Normally it would be something like this:

```
$ echo "$((2 * 3))"
```

But I need to get the result by accessing the expression from the `multiply.txt` file and producing the result on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat multiply.txt 
2*3
$ echo $(( $(cat multiply.txt) ))
6
```

Comment: How about if a file have multiple expression? like 2*3 and in next line 4*8.

Comment: That depends on what you expect the output to be. If you're expecting an output line for each line in the file, then you can't do it with just `echo` and `cat`, you need more advanced things like `while` and `read`, or just `bc`.